# Compare object pointers in operator==

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Doing some code maintenance, I've found something that **need to simplified** in favour of better reading and less lines of codes.
Consider the following sample class:

```
class MyClass
{

public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(Object1* o1, Object2* o2, Object3* o3, Object4* o4);
    ~MyClass();

    MyClass &operator=(const MyClass &other);
    void copy(const MyClass &other);
    bool operator==(const MyClass &other) const;

    ...

private:
    Object1* o1 = 0;
    Object2* o2 = 0;
    Object3* o3 = 0;
    Object4* o4 = 0;
};
```

This class is made of 1 to 4 optional objects.

Since these object could be null, when I come to the *equal operator* I've found the following:

```
bool MyClass::operator==(const MyClass &other) const
{
    if (o1 && (other.o1 == NULL)) return false;
    if ((o1 == NULL) && other.o1) return false;
    if (o1 && other.o1){ if (*o1!= *other.o1) return false; }
    if (o2 && (other.o2 == NULL)) return false;
    if ((o2 == NULL) && other.o2) return false;
    if (o2 && other.o2){ if (*o2!= *other.o2) return false; }
    if (o3 && (other.o3 == NULL)) return false;
    if ((o3 == NULL) && other.o3) return false;
    if (o3 && other.o3){ if (*o3!= *other.o3) return false; }
    if (o4 && (other.o4 == NULL)) return false;
    if ((o4 == NULL) && other.o4) return false;
    if (o4 && other.o4){ if (*o4!= *other.o4) return false; }
    return true;
}
```

I don't want to bring the discussion if the equal operator is needed or not, I just want to know if there's a way to simplify the above code.

General speaking: what is the most standard and efficient way to compare object pointers in the equal operator?

Comment: Could somebody be so kind to explain why the downvotes?

Comment: Someone might have interpreted this as an opinion/discussion question. It's pretty close.

Comment: Mmm...question is related to some specific code

Comment: There are more criteria for a good SO question than "relates to some specific code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to simplify the code, stop using pointers and actually use `optional` objects. You can either [wait for `std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (C++17, so just a couple of months and a new compiler probably already supports it), or use Boost:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

class MyClass
{

public:
    MyClass(
       boost::optional<Object1> o1 = boost::none,
       boost::optional<Object2> o2 = boost::none,
       boost::optional<Object3> o3 = boost::none,
       boost::optional<Object4> o4 = boost::none
    ) : o1(o1), o2(o2), o3(o3), o4(o4) {}

private:
    boost::optional<Object1> o1;
    boost::optional<Object2> o2;
    boost::optional<Object3> o3;
    boost::optional<Object4> o4;
};
```

or just roll your own pretty easily.

Now you don't need all those operators‚ or your own copy constructor.

As always, the key is in abstracting away certain logic so that it is neatly re-usable. In this case there is still an `operator==` somewhere, and there is still a copy constructor somewhere, but it's implemented *once* inside the `optional` type and doesn't need recreating *en masse* for each instance. Multiple instances compose naturally.

If you really want to stick with your current implementation, you can at least shorten:

```
if (o1 && (other.o1 == NULL)) return false;
if ((o1 == NULL) && other.o1) return false;
if (o1 && other.o1){ if (*o1!= *other.o1) return false; }
```

to:

```
if (!o1 != !other.o1) return false;
if (o1 && (*o1 != *other.o1)) return false;
```

although it's still a bit ew.

Comment: But, without boost or C++17, are pointers a good choice for optional class members or function parameter?

Comment: @ABCplus: Modulo the above caveats about leaking over-complications into the rest of your code as a consequence, yes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `if (o1 != other.o1) return false;` will incorrectly early-out when `o1` and `other.o1` point to separate but equivalent objects.

Comment: @Quentin: Er oops fixed :D

Comment: Good example of how logic like this is overly error-prone

Answer (score 0):

How about writing comparator that will accept field getter?

```
template< typename TGetter > bool
Eq(MyClass const & left, MyClass const & right, TGetter && getter)
{
    auto const p_left(getter(left));
    auto const p_right(getter(right));
    return((!p_left && !p_right) || (p_left && p_right && (*p_left == *p_right)));
}

bool MyClass::operator==(const MyClass &other) const
{
    return
    (
        Eq(*this, other, [](const MyClass & inst){return inst.o1;})
        &&
        Eq(*this, other, [](const MyClass & inst){return inst.o2;})
        &&
        Eq(*this, other, [](const MyClass & inst){return inst.o3;})
        &&
        Eq(*this, other, [](const MyClass & inst){return inst.o4;})
    );
)
```

Comment: It's much easier to read, at least. Needs a better name than `Eq` though, given that it assumes the result of `getter` is a pointer to be dereferenced.